# I would like to add an additional row to my Wordpress BootStrap Navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple website which I would like to add a row above the navigation that would contain a phone number and maybe some social links.

I am a theme called Hestia Pro and cannot find where to add this extra row

I am looking for some pointers as to where this would get added in the sites theme.

The website is www.gpoint.co.uk

Craig

Answer (score 0):

Your theme is built with bootstrap 
you can check your theme files and go to header.php
check the the tag `<header>` 
and inside it you can add:

```
<header>
.....


<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
       Telephone
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
       email
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
       support
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
```

thats it :)

Comment: I have tried that and it did not do as intended as the header changes when you scroll up the page. this is the snippet in the header.php

<div class="wrapper">
   
  <header class="header">
   <?php do_action( 'hestia_do_header' ); ?>